# Jquery: form validation

Tags: regex, jquery-validate, validation

i'm using jquery validation plugin and i'attempting to define a rule for the only field of form: The value of the field must contain a string of five numbers( **the field value will always contain letters** ). I've try with the rule **required( dependency-callback )** and got something like that:

```
rules: {
    field: {
      required: function(element) {
        var value_field = $('#field').attr('value');
      }
    }
  }
```

Now i need to search value_field for a string of five numbers.
Am i using the good rule for this case? And how to search for the needed string?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom method to the validator before you setup the validator with your rules:

```
$.validator.addMethod("FiveDigits", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{5}$/.test(value);
}, "A 5 digit number please");
```

then use the following rule :

`fieldName : { required : true, FiveDigits: true }`

Answer (score 1):

```
// define variables
var field_value, regexp;
// set field_value to #field's value
field_value = $("field").val();
// the regular expression that matches the pattern we're looking for
regexp = /\d{5}/;
if (field_value.match(regexp)) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code seems to be good but i can't finding how to apply it with jquery validate. I've add a new method with your code but it don't work.